# Reference source code line in minted package

Tags: cross-referencing, minted

Does anybody know a working example, where a source code line is reference in minted?
I have not found any help till now how to do this?

```
\begin{minted}[linenos=true]{c++}
    bla bla bla bla ;   \label{myline}
\end{minted}
```

The above does not work, unfortunately, there is not `commandchars` or excape for latex commands only for math?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Keep in mind that [minted](https://github.com/gpoore/minted) now is the recommended package for using pygments.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `mathescape`, then put your `\label` in math mode in a comment:

```
\begin{minted}[linenos=true, mathescape]{c++}
    i = i + 1 ;  
    j = j + 1 ; // The important line $\label{myline}$
    k = k + 1 ;
\end{minted}
The important line is line \ref{myline}.
```

Comment: cool :-)! works!

Comment: Yes, it works for me too but not as well as desired.  It inserts right line number as link but this link points to whole listing, not a mentioned line.  Anyway you should accept this answer.

Comment: Is it correct that there's no way (with `mathescape`) to specify a label _without_ requiring a comment symbol?

Comment: @Mark Unfortunately I think this will require editing the relevant Pygments lexer – everything gets taken over to Pygments before LaTeX has a chance to edit bits out. Incidentally you can use the `texcomments` option instead of `mathescape` to avoid having to put the `\label` in math mode.

Comment: Works at `c++`, doesn't work for `xml` language.

Comment: Works for `python` with the comment symbol `#`. Also, we can refer to a label in the code with `$\ref{}$` in math mode!

Comment: My code is plenty of $ symbols and they are not comments, they are used in the R language to specify variables inside dataframes.
How can I keep them and still use the mathscape trick?

Answer (score 16):

@Ant's answer is great, but requires that your `\label` go inside a comment that will appear in the rendered code. You can get around this by using `escapeinside` instead of `mathescape`:

```
\begin{minted}[linenos=true, escapeinside=!!]{c++}
    i = i + 1 ;  
    j = j + 1 ; !\label{myline}!
    k = k + 1 ;
\end{minted}
The important line is line \ref{myline}.
```

Comment: Can I use any delimiter?
It's difficult to find a symbol not already used in the code for other things.
Is it possible to use longer delimiters instead of a single character?

Comment: I have my minted code in an appendix.
Your solution points to the appendix but not to the line of code nor even the page where the label is located.
How can I get it?

Answer (score 3):

If you are happy to change from `minted` to `listings` then it is possible as this example shows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  escapeinside={(*}{*)},
  numbers=left
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
  def foo
    while do bar(*\label{line}*)
  end
\end{lstlisting}
As we can see in line \ref{line}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this means a lot more work to get nice colourful syntax highlighting. `escapeinside` defines a way to escape the verbatim environment and have what's inside the `(*` and `*)` actually read by TeX...

Comment: So it's a choice between nice colors and line references... or patching the package for everybody's benefit!

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can refer to a single line of code. You can however embed the `minted` call in a `listing` environment and refer to that listing:

```
\begin{listing}
  \begin{minted}[linenos=true]{c++}
    bla bla bla bla ;   \label{myline}
  \end{minted}
  \caption{My nice listing}
  \label{lst:nice_listing}
\end{listing}

In line~2 of listing \ref{lst:nice_listing}, we can see that...
```

Comment: With listings you can refer to a single line of the code. I'd be amazed if minted couldn't do the same.

Comment: @Seamus: as a matter of fact, it's not mentioned in the documentation at least.

Comment: yes I just looked. I am amazed. As I said I would be...

Comment: @Seamus How do you refer to a single line in listings? Thanks!

Comment: @Alenanno look at my answer to this question.