# Reference source code line in minted environment with cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, minted, cleveref

I'd like to reference lines in the `minted` environment (solved [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24945/reference-source-code-line-in-minted-package) for regular `\ref`) using cleveref.

MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = arara
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

\begin{minted}[linenos=true, mathescape]{c}
int i = 0;
int j = 1; // label $\label{ln:unreachable1}$
\end{minted}

Test with ref: \ref{ln:unreachable1}

Test with cref: \cref{ln:unreachable1}

\end{document}
```

Gives

[image]

i.e. the containing section instead of "line $number".

Comment: I'm afraid you're out of luck. This almost certainly requires explicit support in `cleveref`, which doesn't exist yet. And I'm unlikely to have time to add it myself anytime soon. It might be easy to code the necessary support yourself, or it might be hard, depending on how the `minted` environment is implemented. The `algorithmicx` support already in `cleveref` might give you some clues. If you send me a patch to `cleveref` to add `minted` support, I'd certainly consider applying it.

Answer (score 6):

Although, one cannot get it directly to work, there is a workaround:

```
\newcommand{\Vlabel}[1]{\label[line]{#1}\hypertarget{#1}{}}
\newcommand{\lref}[1]{\hyperlink{#1}{\FancyVerbLineautorefname~\ref*{#1}}}
```

Make the label with `\Vlabel{label}` and then use `\lref{label}`. I know, this is not much better than manually writing the link. At least, hyperlinks are working.

With `[line]`, I could get `cleveref` print out "Line" instead of the section, but the reference is still wrong.

The solution is based on the discussion at http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2008-12/msg00075.html.