# How to teach \cref to refer to lines inside "minted" environments?

Tags: minted, cleveref

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[linenos,escapeinside=||]{cpp}
Hello,
world! |\label{foo}|
\end{minted}
See line no.\ref{foo}.
See \cref{foo}.
\end{document}
```

It renders:

[image]

How to fix?

Comment: related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132420/reference-source-code-line-in-minted-environment-with-cleveref

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if that's a possibility for you, but `zref-clever` can handle the case:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\AddToHook{env/minted/begin}{\zcsetup{currentcounter=FancyVerbLine}}
\zcsetup{countertype={FancyVerbLine=line}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[linenos,escapeinside=||]{cpp}
Hello,
world! |\label{foo}|
\end{minted}
See line no.~\ref{foo}.
See \zcref{foo}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I don't know `minted` very well and just gave it a quick look and, as far as I can tell, it uses the `FancyVerbLine` counter for line numbering. Also, `minted` seems to resort to a hard to track resetting behavior when `langlinenos` is enabled. That might well confuse the above setup, and would probably require further investigation and fine-tuning. (I don't think the consequences would be serious though. Things like if labels to two "lines 3" of different languages were to be referenced in the same command, `zref-clever` would not be able to distinguish between them and would compress them into one. But both of them are of type `line` anyway, so it would be somewhat strange to typeset "lines 3 and 3" instead of just "line 3").