# Highlight labeled lines of code with minted

Tags: minted

I was wondering whether I could use the labeling mechanism explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483714/85983) to get the line numbers that I want to use for [highlighting code via `highlightlines`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498614/85983) in minted.

I am imagining something like this (Modified example from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483714/85983):

```
\begin{minted}[linenos=true, escapeinside=!!, highlightlines=\ref{myline}]{c++}
    i = i + 1 ;  
    j = j + 1 ; !\label{myline}!
    k = k + 1 ;
\end{minted}
The important line is line \ref{myline}.
```

In the resulting output the line `j = j + 1 ;` should be highlighted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `\ref` and `\pageref` are not fully expandable, but [`refcount` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) provides a `\getrefnumber{<label name>}` which fully expands to the linked counter value of that `<label name>`. Hence your requirement can be implemented by:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{refcount}

\makeatletter
% expand value of key "highlightlines"
\define@key{FV}{highlightlines}{\edef\FV@HighlightLinesList{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[
    linenos=true, 
    escapeinside=!!, 
    highlightlines={\getrefnumber{myline}, \getrefnumber{yourline}}
  ]{c++}
    i = i + 1 ;  
    j = j + 1 ; !\label{myline}!
    k = k + 1 ;
    l = l + 1 ; !\label{yourline}!
\end{minted}
The important lines are line~\ref{myline} and line\ref{yourline}.

\end{document}
```

[image]