# What is wrong with my system setup?

Tags: xetex, cjk, miktex2.9, xecjk

I bought a new computer with windows10, which I installed MikTeX2.9.
The previous LaTeX file failed to compile in this new system.
The follwing is a min. example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[BoldFont,SlantFont,CheckSingle=true]{xeCJK} 
\usepackage{CJKnumb}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setCJKmainfont{DFT_HZ5.TTC} 
\begin{document}
請見本書第\CJKnumber{\ref{coding}}章)。
\end{document}
```

You do not need to use DFT_HZ5.TTC any other Chinese font is the same.
The following is the log file:

```
....
....
Font)                  TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n --> TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/b/n on 
input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/b/it on input lin
e 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/b/n on input line 7.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.8 隢?
```

It is not peculiar, because what is inside \CJKnumber is undefined.
The program should popup and ask me, and I simple need to hit a return
But it did not popup.
The program simply break here.

However, if I remove the other Chinese character, the program become

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[BoldFont,SlantFont,CheckSingle=true]{xeCJK} 
\usepackage{CJKnumb}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setCJKmainfont{DFT_HZ5.TTC} 
\begin{document}
\CJKnumber{\ref{coding}}
\end{document}
```

It is fine.
What is wrong with my system setup?

Comment: Could you please add code the code where you set `\label{coding}`?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549882/79060), the error is caused by the fact that `\ref{<label>}` is not fully expandable (mainly because the `\null` in `\@setref`). Instead, you can use the fully expandable command `\getrefnumber{<label>}` from `refcount` package.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[BoldFont,SlantFont,CheckSingle=true]{xeCJK} 
\usepackage{CJKnumb}
\usepackage{refcount}

\begin{document}
\chapter{title}\label{coding}
第\CJKnumber{\getrefnumber{coding}}章
\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, to have consistent counter output format, it is recommended to (re)define `\the<counter>` command.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[BoldFont,SlantFont,CheckSingle=true]{xeCJK} 
\usepackage{CJKnumb}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\CJKnumber{\arabic{chapter}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{title}\label{coding}
第\ref{coding}章

\end{document}
```

Note that `\CJKnumber` accepts a number, not counter name, so we firstly use `\arabic{chapter}` to get the number.

This usage is more common.

Comment: How about 第\CJKnumber{\thechapter}章 \hfill}
Which command should I replace for \thechapter?   This issue can be fixed using "chcp 65001" under command mode, at the cost of conflict at other software. It is a issue about UTF-8 coding.

Comment: @ophage I edited my answer to add a redefining `\thechapter` resolution.