# what is wrong with this error message

Tags: miktex, windows, miktex2.9

My notebook has only one disk c:
I installed MikTex on C: and compile simpson.tex on C:
Presumably the C: prohibit written into it?
But I granted privilege. What else should I do in view of the following error message?

```
2020-06-17 19:31:58,613+0800 INFO  xelatex - this process (10128) started by 'cmd' with command line: xelatex simpson
2020-06-17 19:31:58,665+0800 INFO  xelatex - allowing known shell commands
2020-06-17 19:31:58,669+0800 INFO  xelatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-06-17 19:32:03,124+0800 FATAL xelatex.core - No space left on device
2020-06-17 19:32:03,124+0800 FATAL xelatex.core - Function: putc
2020-06-17 19:32:03,124+0800 FATAL xelatex.core - Result: 28
2020-06-17 19:32:03,124+0800 FATAL xelatex.core - Data: <no data>
2020-06-17 19:32:03,124+0800 FATAL xelatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex/C4P/C4P.h:482
2020-06-17 19:32:03,128+0800 FATAL xelatex - No space left on device
2020-06-17 19:32:03,128+0800 FATAL xelatex - Info: 
2020-06-17 19:32:03,128+0800 FATAL xelatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex/C4P/C4P.h
2020-06-17 19:32:03,128+0800 FATAL xelatex - Line: 482
2020-06-17 19:32:03,144+0800 INFO  xelatex - this process (10128) finishes with exit code 1
2020-06-17 19:32:03,156+0800 WARN  miktex.core - still open: simpson.tex
2020-06-17 19:32:03,156+0800 WARN  miktex.core - still open: simpson.log
2020-06-17 19:32:03,160+0800 WARN  miktex.core - still open: simpson.aux
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "on C:", but I would always put documents inside the documents folder.

Comment: "On C:" means on C: disk. I indeed put documents inside the documents folder.

Comment: can you compile a pdflatex document?

Comment: Here is a similar bug report: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/41
It is worth trying the workaround: "Try executing chcp 65001 before xelatex and see if it solves your problem."

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I can compile pdflatex and XelaTeX without using CJK font (i.e. CHinese characters)

Comment: Then you should a minimal example that demonstrates the issue, so that tests are possible,

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  The example is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548845/what-is-wrong-with-my-system-setup

Comment: @ChristianSchenk I have looked at the gihub link you provided. Yes, it is indeed the same issue. But I don't know what is their conclusion. The discussion seems closed. I do not think it is related to Window version or MiKTeX version. Someone mentioned somehow change the console mode to UTF-8 I don't know how to do that. What is the "try to excute chcp 65001 before xelatex" you mentioned?

Comment: I can't test that. I don't have the font.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you can use any chinese font. The are the same.

Comment: It can be solved by typing chcp 65001 in cmd. But do not know how to change it permanently.

Comment: But using chcp 65001 will cause other problems in my systems, i.e. my macro in Excel reference a sheet with Chinese name.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Which language does your pc use? Is there something non-ascii char in your user name?

Comment: I suspect that "No space left on device" message means something ... Maybe that no space left on device, who know ... I would try to check if there are some free space in the hard disk.